# git for development and svn on production server

Tags: git, svn, deployment, integration

I have an website on development using git as control version system, and the client insist in us to use svn to deploy the website (they don't believe that git is a stable tool to install on their server) so I'm looking for a way to continue developing using git, which my dev team already know better than svn, and just move the release code on to a svn repository, so the client can deploy on their production server.

Since this website will continually be update by my team, I don't belive in copying code, by hand, to an svn repo and than make an package on it.

I'm looking for a way to develop on git, and run a specific command that will send an git tag (which represents an version of the site) to an different svn repository, is this possible?

thanks.

Comment: http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [git-svn](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html).

It allows you to operate between an svn repo and git. Use git locally and commit to svn.

Answer (score 1):

You may install [SubGit](http://subgit.com) (created exactly for those purposes) into your SVN server. After that it creates a pure Git interface to the SVN server, so both interfaces are usable. Every push to the Git repository is translated into SVN commit and vice versa (the translation is driven by hooks). Simultaneous push to Git and SVN is not a problem.

To install SubGit you run

```
$ subgit configure path/to/svn/repository
$ #optionally edit path/to/svn/repository/conf/subgit.conf to setup different parameters (like path where to create Git repository) or path/to/svn/repository/conf/authors.txt to setup non-default Git<->SVN authors mapping
$ subgit install path/to/svn/repository
```

By default the linked Git repository will appear at path/to/svn/repository/.git.